# SQL Server multiple select on an Offset...fetch...next query

Tags: sql-server, datatables, offset

I'm trying to get data into datatables (js library for data table) by server-side processing.

The data should be produced as below

```
+---------+--------+--------+
|  Name   | TotalA | TotalB |
+---------+--------+--------+
| Person1 |     10 |     40 |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

The query that I tried

```
select 
    a.Name,
    (select count(*) from SummaryA where id = a.id) as TotalA,
    (select count(*) from SummaryB where id = a.id) as TotalB
from
    records a
order by 
    a.Name
    offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only
```

and

```
select
    aa.Name,
    (select count(*) from SummaryA where id = aa.id) as TotalA,
    (select count(*) from SummaryB where id = aa.id) as TotalB
from 
    (select 
         a.Name, a.id
     from 
         records a
     order by 
         a.Name
         offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only) as aa
```

However, these queries will result in an error as below

> Error in query: Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

Running below query is not a problem

```
select 
    a.Name
from
    records a
    offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only
```

Comment: what database are you using ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64) Jun 17 2016 19:14:09 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: your first query looks fine. the 2nd query, you missed the id in the inner query.

Comment: @Squirrel sorry.....corrected,....

Comment: you still get the same error on both query ?

Comment: yes...still get the same error...

Answer (score 1):

Issue- offset_row_count_expression can be a variable, parameter, or constant scalar subquery. When a subquery is used, **it cannot reference any columns defined in the outer query scope**.
 [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Try

```
    ;with temp as (select a.name ,
     count(b.id) as TotalA ,
    count(c.id) as Totalb
FROM records a
   left join  SummaryA b
      b.id=a.id
  left join SummaryB  c
      c.id=a.id
group by a.name)

select * from temp
order by temp.Name
Offset 0 rows
fetch next 10 rows only
```

This can also be solved

```
 with tmp as (
    select a.name ,
         a.id
    FROM records a
    order by temp.Name
    Offset 0 rows
    fetch next 10 rows only
    )

    select a.name ,
         count(b.id) as TotalA ,
        count(c.id) as Totalb
    FROM tmp a
       left join  SummaryA b
          b.id=a.id
      left join SummaryB  c
          c.id=a.id
    group by a.name order by a.Name
```

Comment: I have updated query because  offset_row_count_expression can be a variable, parameter, or constant scalar subquery. When a subquery is used, it cannot reference any columns defined in the outer query   scope. That is, it cannot be correlated with the outer query.    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: so...i need to add them in a temp table then do offset from there....but the data is too large...

Comment: Yes either temptable or CTE.

Comment: You can do offset first and get names and then do count calclution